# Can we disable validate server certificate option under Protected EAP Properties

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Can you help me to disable Validate Server Certificate option in Local Area Network Properties
Authentication Tab .I want to disable validate server certificate check with the help of batch file.
thanks
Umair

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for requires a hotfix from Microsoft for Win7/Win2008 systems:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2493933

Hotfixes can be scripted, usually by following them with a /s or /q for "silent" or "quiet", or both.